# Algorithm to determine paths that define shape of connected rectangles

Tags: computational-geometry, computer-vision

Say you have a bunch of rectangles like these:

[image]

They get organized into 3 distinct final shapes like this:

[image]

As you can see, there are a few "complete contours", as in here:

[image]

The way you figure out the contour of the thing is by *visually* going around the edge of the final shape, sort of like this:

[image]

The question is, given that you start with *a set of arbitrarily sized curves*, in this case, *rectangles* (assume they were drawn as real rectangles), how to efficiently/effectively figure out what the final **paths** are on the final set of shapes. So in the pink drawing, there are 4 paths that define the whole system. I am having a hard time imagining how you would formulate this as perhaps a graph theory problem or something in order to iterate through a list of rectangles, determine their "connectivity", then create some sort of mental sketch of the "perimeter". It seems like it would get complicated fast.

Wondering if there are any areas of research that delve into this stuff, or if there is a straightforward solution to the problem.

Comment: Do you have all "blocks" in advance? Your input is set of shapes and final raster? There are ideas like skeletonization, vectorization, blob detection, shape detection, Viola-Jones descriptors, feature detection, crossing point detection and many more concepts ressembling your problem. That said, I have a hard time understanding what is the input and what is your goal. What do you mean by paths? If your curves are given than finding intersections and "connectivity" is a good start, but what is next point? Finding blobs and detecting loops?

Comment: Yes I have all the blocks in advance. The shapes are in a data structure with width/height/x/y/bezier/etc. like svg path.

Comment: Can segments of the rectangles have any orientation ? Or only along 2 orthogonal axis ?

Comment: I don't understand the problem statement.  You want to find out what "the final paths" are, but what do you mean by "the final paths"?  That phrase is never defined.  Can you edit the question to clarify what is the input and what is the desired output?